# `WEEKDAY` function gives the wrong value?

Tags: excel, time, vba

I am in London GMT Time Zone.

If I plug into my excel:

`=IF(OR(WEEKDAY(F20)=6;WEEKDAY(F20)=7);TRUE;FALSE)`

[image]

I get `TRUE` back which is clearly wrong because it is a `Friday` in my Time Zone!

However, this is wrong see here:

[29.12.2006](http://www.dayoftheweek.org/?m=December&d=29&y=2006&go=Go)

Why is this error is excel?

I appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: Um, you haven't shown what the result is...

Comment: Dates don't *have* time zones. Are you sure it's even interpreting your date correctly?

Comment: @JonSkeet I just want to check if the date is a weekend or not. Therefore I use the `excel` function, `WEEKDAY()`. Do not know why this does not work...

Comment: Excel work, you're just interpreting the values incorrectly.

Comment: + 1. Why a downvote? It is a perfectly normal question to ask. Not everyone knows about the 2nd parameter of `WEEKDAY`

Comment: @pnuts: If there was a complete lack of research then I understand but as the hyperlink shows, OP tried to sort it out by himself. But anyways, we all are entitled to our opinions...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`WEEKDAY(F20)` will be 6 - which is Friday.

From the [documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/weekday-HP005209336.aspx):

> The day is given as an integer, ranging from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday), by default.

So 6 is a Friday.

It looks like you should be checking whether `WEEKDAY(F20)` is 1 or 7, if you're trying to find out if it's a weekend.

If you *want* to use Monday (1) - Sunday (7) you need to pass in a second value of 2 to the function:

```
WEEKDAY(F20, 2)
```

(Again, see the documentation.)

Comment: Wow Jon in Excel forum :p + 1 Yup it's all about the `ReturnType`.

Comment: @user5414: And that's why the first thing you should always do when something doesn't behave as you expect it to is consult the documentation :)